# Creating a wrapper class for a curl command in Java

Tags: java, curl, wrapper

I am trying to write a wrapper class, that is a class which would make requests and handle responses of the following curl command, in java.

The curl command is:

```
curl  -XPOST 'http://sda.tech/earl/api/processQuery' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d"{\"nlquery\":\"Who is the president of Russia?\"}"
```

Comment: What kind of OS are you using? Also what kind of Java version?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your question, but you should still improve it yourself, too. It is not clear what you mean with "wrapper"? Do you want to write java code that uses java libs to make a HTTP connection, sends data, and reads results? Or do you want to write java code that calls curl? It is simply not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes @GhostCat  thats exactly what I need.

Comment: I asked an OR question. "A or B?" "Yes, I need that". Sorry, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So sorry @GhostCat I want a java code that calls curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that is imperative for you to use `cURL` and not any out of the box Java HTTP client, you could create a simple wrapper that will use Java's `Process` API to invoke the underlying `cURL` executable.

A very simple client like so would something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Curl {

    public enum HttpMethod { GET, PUT, POST, DELETE }

    private final String endpoint;
    public String getEndpoint() { return endpoint; }

    private final HttpMethod method;
    public HttpMethod getMethod() { return method; }

    private final String data;
    public String getData() { return data; }

    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() { return headers; }

    private Curl(String endpoint, HttpMethod method, String data, Map<String, String> headers) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.method = method;
    this.data = data;
    this.headers = headers;
    }

    public String call() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();

    command.add("curl");
    command.add("-s");
    command.add("-X");
    command.add(method.name());
    command.add("\"" + endpoint + "\"");

    if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("\"");
        headers.keySet().forEach(s -> builder.append(s).append(":").append(headers.get(s)));
        builder.append("\"");
        command.add("-H");
        command.add(builder.toString());
    }

    if (data != null) {
        command.add("-d");
        command.add("\"" + data + "\"");
        command.add(data);
    }

    return doCurl(command.toArray(new String[0]));
    }

    private String doCurl(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();

        String lines;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            lines = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
    process.waitFor();
        return lines;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private String endpoint;
        private HttpMethod method;
        private String data;
        private Map<String, String> headers;

        public Builder(String endpoint) {
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public Builder method(HttpMethod method) {
            this.method = method;
            return this;
    }

    public Builder data(String data) {
            this.data = data;
            return this;
    }

    public Builder headers(Map<String, String> headers) {
            this.headers = headers;
            return this;
    }

    public Curl create() {
            if (endpoint == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Endpoint cannot be null");
        }

        if (method == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP method cannot be null");
        }
        return new Curl(endpoint, method, data, headers);
    }

    }

}
```

Invoking the call to the endpoint could then be done as simple as this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String data = "{\\\"nlquery\\\":\\\"Who is the president of Russia?\\\"}";

        String result = new Curl.Builder("http://sda.tech/earl/api/processQuery")
        .method(Curl.HttpMethod.POST)
        .headers(map)
        .data(data)
        .create()
        .call();


    System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Mind you as I said before I don't see the reason why you would not want to use Java components (for example Java 9 and onward has a native HTTP client https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient.html) but hey I suppose that this is for some sort of assignment so what you need to use may be limited in term of options.

I have tried the above only for the use case you want it to be used, but I don't see how this would not work for other cases too.

Comment: 9+ has the supposedly improved HttpClient in incubator, but Java has had `java.net.URL->HttpURLConnection` since the Clinton administration.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 loved the comment :D

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I tried running this but I am not getting any response. Can you please help me out.

Comment: What type of OS and Java version are you using?

Comment: Using Java 8 and Linux(Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Remove the `-s` option from the command creating method to see more detail regarding it's output. Also `cURL` expects single quotes for the URL and the headers in Linux, which is not the case for Windows (double quotes). You might need to do some slight code alterations to get it working.

Comment: Hey! I made the necessary changes and now I get the following output-
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
curl: (3) Port number ended with '"'

Comment: You're not formatting your data correctly. As I said before try experiment with the usage of quotes. Windows and Linux usage single and double quotes in a very different manner. When I posted the original question I wrote this sample on Windows thus as I said before you might to do some adjustments for it to run on Linux.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I tried a lot but the error still remains. If you can help me out it would be great.

Comment: @MarkBurrow you have to share the code you have at the moment.

Comment: I solved the error. Thakyou for helping me @Aris_Kortex.

Comment: @MarkBurrow what was the issue? Also if my answer was helpful please go ahead and upvote the question.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex it was with the data as you had mentioned. Changing the data part of the code did the trick. So sorry I am not yet able to upvote due to low reputation points.

Comment: @MarkBurrow no worries mate, I am happy to have helped you in the first. On last question though, how come you're not using any higher level Java utilities to do this and rely on `cURL` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ProcessBuilder:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

I use it in my CommandLineProcess class (constructor does all the work):

```
private Process p;

public Process getProcess() {
    return p;
}

public
CommandLineProcess
(String[] commandWithParams, String executionDirectory, boolean waitFor)
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandWithParams);
    pb.directory(new File(executionDirectory));

    try {

        p = pb.start();
        if (waitFor) {
            p.waitFor();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.getInstance().error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.getInstance().error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the purpose of writing a wrapper for curl. You could use existing classes URL, HttpClient or RestClient.